# How to work with the StringTokenizer class

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

I am supposed to evaluate a string by splitting the string in tokens using the StringTokenizer class. After that I am supposed to convert these tokens to int values, using "Integer.parseInt".

What I don't get is how I am supposed to work with the tokens after splitting them.

```
public class Tester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String i = ("2+5");
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(i, "+-", true);
    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        System.out.println(st.nextToken());
    }
    int x = Integer.parseInt();
//what exactly do I have to type in here, do convert the token(s) to an int value?
}

}
```

So if I understand this right I now have three tokens. That would be: "2", "+" and "5".

How exactly do I convert these tokens to int values?
Do I have to convert each of them seperatly?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You must store the value returned from `st.nextToken()` in a String variable.  Also, documentation is your friend;  the [Integer.parseInt documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) should help you.

Comment: Right now you are printing out your tokens to standard output, but not saving them anywhere. Consider saving the output of st.nextToken() in an array and then you can access that later to perform Integer.parseInt()

Comment: [*`StringTokenizer` is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the `split` method of `String` or the java.util.regex package instead.*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use this:

```
    String i = ("2+5");
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(i, "+-", true);
    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String tok=st.nextToken();
        System.out.println(tok);

        //what exactly do I have to type in here, do convert the token(s) to an int value?
        if ("+-".contains(tok)) {
            //tok is an operand
        }
        else {
            int x = Integer.parseInt(tok);
        }       
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To have a possibility to make some calculations with the Integers extracted from the String, you have to put them into an ArrayList. And you have to use try/catch operation to avoid a NumberFormatException. Further you can take the values directly from the ArrayList and do with them what you'd like. For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList <Integer> myArray = new ArrayList <>();    
    String i = ("2+5");
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(i, "+-/*=", true);
        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            try {
            Integer stg = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken(i));
            myArray.add(stg);
                }
            catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {};
            }

       System.out.println("This is an array of Integers: " + myArray);
       for (int a : myArray) {
           int x = a;
           System.out.println("This is an Integer: " + x);
       }
       int b = myArray.get(0);
       int c = myArray.get(1);
       System.out.println("This is b: " + b);
       System.out.println("This is c: " + c);
       System.out.println("This is a sum of b + c: " + (b + c));

}
```

As a result you'll get:

```
This is an array of Integers: [2, 5]
This is an Integer: 2
This is an Integer: 5
This is b: 2
This is c: 5
This is a sum of b + c: 7
```